# Python - Predicting the probability of 6 Heads or Tails in a row from a set sample size

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm wondering whether there is a way to make this even more efficient or reduce the number of variables.

```py
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
results = []
head_streak = ['H'] * 6
tail_streak = ['T'] * 6
sample_size = 1000000
for i, experimentNumber in enumerate(range(sample_size)):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    results.append(random.choice(('H', 'T')))

    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    try:
        temp = results[i-5:]
        if temp == head_streak or temp == tail_streak:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
    except:
        pass

print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / sample_size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    results.append(random.choice(('H', 'T')))
```

This comment is severely misleading: the code does not create a list of 100 values, it create an infinitely growing list that extends up to `sampleSize` values by the time the program terminates.

---

Independently of the misleading comment, this is a bad idea, and can be avoided by limiting the size of the `results` list in some say (`del results[:-6]`, or `results = results[-6:]`, I'm not sure which is better). This would also obsolete the `temp` variable, because the `results` array would no longer contain extra flips.

---

```
    try:
        temp = results[i-5:]
        if temp == head_streak or temp == tail_streak:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
    except:
        pass
```

Bare `except` statements are a bad idea. Bare `except:pass` statements even more so. Among other problems, it means that if you press Ctrl-C while your code is executing that section, the code won't exit.

It's not clear what exception you are trying to catch (`results[i-5:]` doesn't throw an error if `results` is less than five items long; it just truncates the list), so I can't suggest a direct replacement, but I would recommend either catching a specific exception, or removing the try-catch entirely.

---

Python lists natively support negative indexing, so you can simplify `results[i-5:]` to `results[-6:]` and remove the `i` variable entirely. As suggested by the question asker in the comments, this makes the `enumerate` call unnecessary.

---

The `i` variable will then be unused. It's clearer to name variables you don't use as `_`, so it's easy to tell that they aren't used.

---

Full code:

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
results = []
head_streak = ['H'] * 6
tail_streak = ['T'] * 6
sample_size = 1000000
for _ in range(sample_size):
    # Code that generates another 'heads' or 'tails' value
    results.append(random.choice(('H', 'T')))

    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 5 heads or tails in a row.
    results = results[-6:]
    if results == head_streak or results == tail_streak:
        numberOfStreaks += 1

print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / sample_size))
```

Comment: in that case i wouldn't even need enumerate would i, for i in range(samplesize) works

Answer (score 3):

## Eliminating useless code

Enumerating a range is really pointless

```
In [6]: sample_size = 5

In [7]: for i, experimentNumber in enumerate(range(sample_size)):
   ...:     print(i, experimentNumber)
   ...:     
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

So we can easily replace one by the other. We do not even need to replace as `experimentNumber` is not used anywhere. Next we notice that `i` is also used only once where we can replace `results[i-5:]` by superior construct `results[-6:]`.
We also eliminate the superfluous exception handling. So far this is already covered by @ppperys answer.

## Efficiency

you create a complet list of length `sample_size` of random values in memory. This is not required and may be a problem on big sample sizes. As you always need the last 6 values only you could go for `collections.deque` which can maintain a `maxlen`.

```
from collections import deque
results = deque(maxlen=6)
```

For the evaluation made easy we do not use `('H', 'T')` but numbers. We do not need to comare with a streak any more but do it arithmetically. Here is the only pitfall - we must check if the queue is filled completely to not accidentally accept a short sequence of zeros.

```
for _ in range(sample_size):
    results.append(random.choice((0, 1)))
    if len(results) == 6 and sum(results) in (0, 6):
        numberOfStreaks += 1
```

This not only saves memory but we also get rid of a temporary `temp` and the predifined `head_streak` and `tail_streak`. We notice the magic number `6` appearing multiple times - use a variable. We also make a testable function. We end up with

```
import random
from collections import deque

def streak_probability(streak_len, sample_size):
    results = deque(maxlen=streak_len)
    numberOfStreaks = 0
    for _ in range(sample_size):
        results.append(random.choice((0, 1)))
        if len(results) == streak_len and sum(results) in (0, streak_len):
            numberOfStreaks += 1
    return numberOfStreaks / sample_size


print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (streak_probability(6, 1000000))
```

## Algorithm

This simulation will give good results for big numbers of `sample_size`. However if the sample size was smaller than `6` it will always return `0`. As you divide the final streak count by the sample size you indicate, that you would like to get the probability of a streak per "additional" coin toss. So we should fill the queue before starting to count. That way an average of a large number of runs with a small sample size would match a single run of a large sample size. If we prefill we do not have to check the fill state of the queue (yes I filled to the max while one less would be sufficient).

```
def prefilled_streak_probability(streak_len, sample_size):
    results = deque((random.choice((0, 1)) for _ in range(streak_len)), maxlen=streak_len)
    numberOfStreaks = 0
    for _ in range(sample_size):
        results.append(random.choice((0, 1)))
        if sum(results) in (0, streak_len):
            numberOfStreaks += 1
    return numberOfStreaks / sample_size
```

Now test the difference - we compare the original sample size of 1.000.000 to 100.000 repetitions of sample size 10

```
s=10
n=100000
print('no prefill')
print('Single big sample - Chance of streak: %s%%' % (streak_probability(6, s*n)))
probs = [streak_probability(6, s) for _ in range(n)]
print('Multiple small samples - Chance of streak: %s%%' % (sum(probs)/len(probs)))

print('with prefill')
print('Single big sample - Chance of streak: %s%%' % (prefilled_streak_probability(6, s*n)))
probs = [prefilled_streak_probability(6, s) for _ in range(n)]
print('Multiple small samples - Chance of streak: %s%%' % (sum(probs)/len(probs)))
```

we get

```
no prefill
Single big sample - Chance of streak: 0.031372%
Multiple small samples - Chance of streak: 0.01573599999999932%
with prefill
Single big sample - Chance of streak: 0.031093%
Multiple small samples - Chance of streak: 0.031131999999994574%
```

Comment: You could use `random.choices` and drop the loop for shorter and more readable code.

Comment: @agtoever  Right. But I was explicitely going for a smaller memory footprint. If going for speed I would change not only the random function but also the streak counting.